# NSFetchedResultsController setLimit for each Section

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How would you go about setting the limit of each section in a tableview controlled by a NSFetchedResultsController? For example: I have a bunch of shows that each have start dates and play on different stages. I want to be able to show only who's up next on each stage. So I need not a limit on the whole request, but a limit on each section.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];    

NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > %@", [NSDate date]]];    
request.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
NSSortDescriptor *stageSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"stage.id" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *dateSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:stageSort, dateSort, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"stage.id"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

This kind of works if I limit the it in the tableview delegate methods but often crashes when the fetch changes and it trys to update the table. I think it's because there are a lot more objects in the NSFetchedResultsController than are showing and the animation of changing these breaks it.

How would I go about setting a more effective limit per section? I only want the first result per section.

Comment: 2012-06-01 10:25:40.120 Event Cast[4298:707] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1914.85/UITableView.m:878
2012-06-01 10:25:40.125 Event Cast[4298:707] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think your approach is feasible.

Just fix your table update routines. Before inserting a row, check your logic if it should be done, and if not, skip the insert.